# web tracking tool

Tags: tracking

can any one sugest me which is the best but free web tracking tool ?
I want to know the statics, traffics, hits and area of hits etc...

Comment: Google analytics, but surely this was asked before.

Comment: @Sam - you'd think so, but apparently not: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[tracking]+[web]+traffic+statistics

Answer (score 3):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) is an obvious suggestion. However, if you prefer to host your own solution (because you don't want to send private data to Google for example), then have a look at [Open Web Analytics](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/), a very impressive alternative (see the [features list](http://wiki.openwebanalytics.com/index.php?title=Features)).

> Open Web Analytics (OWA) is an open source web analytics framework written in PHP. OWA was born out of the need for an open source framework that could be used to easily add web analytics features to web sites and applications. The OWA framework also comes with built-in support for popular web applications such as Wordpress and MediaWiki. As a generic web analytics framework, OWA can be extended to track and analyze any web application.
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [openwebanalytics.com](http://www.openwebanalytics.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/owa_dash.jpg))</sub>

Another very decent alternative is [Piwik](http://piwik.org/):

> Piwik is a downloadable, open source
> (GPL licensed) web analytics software
> program. It provides you with detailed
> real time reports on your website
> visitors: the search engines and
> keywords they used, the language they
> speak, your popular pages… and so much
> more.
>
> Piwik aims to be an open source
> alternative to Google Analytics.
>
> Piwik is a PHP MySQL software program
> that you download and install on your
> own webserver. At the end of the five
> minute installation process you will
> be given a JavaScript tag. Simply copy
> and paste this tag on websites you
> wish to track (or use an existing
> plugin to do it automatically for
> you).
>
> [image]
> <sub>(source: [piwik.org](http://piwik.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/11/piwik-e280ba-web-analytics-reports7.png))</sub>

Personally, I prefer OWA over Piwik and don't have anything negative to say about it.

Answer (score 1):

[Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/) has got all the features you specify.

You need a Google account but you don't have to sign up for their advertising programme.  If you are already enrolled, Analytics is hooked into other Google products so you can get reports on Ad Sense hits, etc.

Comment: +1 i am using google analytics...really easy to use and all information you really want.